# When I run cordova on ios it keeps building my old app

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I started a cordova project a while again and needed to do a major update so I cloned the folder and rebuilt the app. I deleted the old xcode project and cordova app but when I run:

```
cordova run ios --device
```

it keeps bring up my old app even though its deleted and no where to be found. If I run it in xcode and target my device it works fine? Is there some kind of caching I need to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with xcode 10 and cordova 8. This fix is to use this instead:

```
cordova run ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
```